# In bash, how to process all user input on command line

Tags: bash, input, sed, stdin

How to make all user input on command line as stdin for a program?

In my case, I want to replace certain words inputed by user. For example, every time user uses the word `animal1`, I want it received as `goldfish`. So it would look like this:

```
$ animal1
goldfish: command not found
```

I tried the following bash command

```
while read input
do
   sed "s/animal2/zebra/g;s/animal1/goldfish/g" <<< "$input"
done
```

But it prompts for user input and does not return to bash. I want it to run while using bash command line.

Also, this allowed me to capture output only.

```
bash | sed 's/animal2/zebra/g;s/animal1/goldfish/g'
```

But not user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, sounds like you just need to set up some aliases:

```
$ alias animal1=goldfish
$ animal1
bash: goldfish: command not found
```

This allows the shell to be used interactively as usual but will make the substitutions you want.

You can add this alias definition to one of your startup files, commonly `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, to have them take effect on any new shell that you open.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by Tom Fenech is good, however, if you plan to add more features to the command you can use a function like the following:

```
animal1() {
    echo "Welcome to the new user interface!"
    goldfish
    # other commands
}
```

and put it in the user `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

The output will be:

```
$>animal1 
Welcome to the new user interface!
-bash: goldfish: command not found
```

By using this approach you can, for example, create a custom output message. In the following snippet I take the return vale from the command and process it word by word. Then I remove the `-bash:` part of the output and reconstruct the message and output it.

```
animal1() {
    echo "Welcome to the new user interface!"
    retval=$(goldfish 2>&1)
    # Now retval stores the output of the command glodfish (both stdout and stderr)
    # we can give it directly to the user
    echo "Default return value"
    echo "$retval"
    echo
    # or test the return value to do something
    # here I build a custom message by removing the bash part 
    message=""
    read -ra flds <<< "$retval"
    for word in "${flds[@]}" #extract substring from the line
        do
            # remove bash
            msg="$(echo "$word" | grep -v bash)"
            # append each word to message
            [[ msg ]] && message="$message $msg"
        done
    echo "Custom message"
    echo "$message"
    echo
}
```

Now the output would:

```
Welcome to the new user interface!
Default return value
-bash: goldfish: command not found

Custom message
  goldfish: command not found
```

If you comment the lines that echoes the default return value then you get exactly the output you asked for.

Comment: Oh very nice! Thank you!